# I uploaded a static website in Render and the website the I uploaded whenever I reloaded any pages aside from the homepage, it renders "not found"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, render

So I uploaded a website on render and whenever I refresh the webpage, the website renders "not found" instead of the content of the page. This happens on all other pages aside from the home page

I think the reason of this behaviour comes from BrowserRouter but I cannot pinpint exactly where the problem is. Here is my App.jsx (Which contains the BrowserRouter)

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/AuthContext";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import EmployeeSignIn from "./pages/EmployeeSignIn";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import OtherProducts from "./pages/OtherProducts";
import EmployeePortal from "./pages/EmployeePortal";
import Error from "./pages/Error";

function App() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <div className="">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} exact />
          <Route path="/products" element={<OtherProducts />}  />
          <Route
            path="/employee-signin"
            element={
              user ? <Navigate to="/employee-portal" /> : <EmployeeSignIn />
            } 
          />
          <Route
            path="/employee-portal"
            element={
              !user ? <Navigate to="/employee-signin" /> : <EmployeePortal />
            }
          />
          <Route path="/*" element={<Error/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <ToastContainer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please help me. I can provide more codes if needed.

Comment: You probably need to add some server side redirect so that so URLs point to your index page since the routing is likely done on the client

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Redirects/Rewirtes** tab for your service in Render and add a rule with the following values
Source: `/*`
Destination: `/index.html`
Action: `Rewrite`

https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app#using-client-side-routing